# Using \endhead is causing my table to not align

Tags: longtable

I attempting to use longtable to layout some tabular data.

This works great:

```
\begin{longtable}{l | l l | l}  
Year & To & From &                      Task \\
2015    & Jan 8 & Jan 9 &               Bla \\
        & Feb 2 & Feb 6 &           Bear \\
        & Feb 9 & Mar 6 &               Water \\
\end{longtable}
```

And looks like this:

[image]

I was wanting to make my header the same when data wraps to a new page so tried this, but suddenly my header no longer aligned.  Whats up?

```
\begin{longtable}{l | l l | l}  
Year & To & From &                      Task \\
\endhead
2015    & Jan 8 & Jan 9 &               Bla \\
        & Feb 2 & Feb 6 &           Bear \\
        & Feb 9 & Mar 6 &               Water \\
\end{longtable}
```

[image]

Comment: that's expected, presumably you got a message from latex telling you that the table widths had changed and to re-run latex. If you re-run latex they should line up.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Looks like you are right.  Why is this?  I am using `pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)` on the command line, is there an argument that I can use to force it to run twice or should I just run twice?  *If you want to more your comment to an answer (unless I get something else extremely insightful) I will award you the bounty.*

Comment: Have you read the documentation? The manual for `longtable` does explain this kind of thing. Perhaps its author does not want to repeat its insights here. It is absolutely standard to need to compile twice at least after making changes to the source of any document. Only very rarely would that not be required. That is pretty much the bog-standard minimal requirement. More complex code would require further runs and/or additional programmes to stabilise the output. You cannot tell the compiler to run itself twice. Either you run it twice or you use another tool to do it for you.

Comment: @cfr - I did read the doc, but I don't have much latex experience.  Just hacking my way through.  Is the requirement to recompile a latex thing or a longtable thing?  How do I figure out if I need to recompile?  Is there an exit status?  If I always compile 10 times, will that be sufficient?

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude Not a `longtable` thing at all. A TeX thing. Recompilation is almost always required except for the very simplest documents. You can tell what more is required by reading the console output. Packages and LaTeX itself will generally (though not, unfortunately, invariably) write messages to the console and log file which tell you what further action is needed and, often, why it is needed. For example, they might tell you to simply recompile, to run Biber or BitTeX, to execute `makeindex` or `makeglossaries` or whatever. Or they may warn you about a change or lost content.

Comment: Or you can use one of various external tools to automate this. However, it is probably best not to automate it until you have a basic sense of how the process works because otherwise it can be much more difficult to find the cause of unexpected output or errors.

Comment: I fear you squandered 50 points of reputation for this!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I got my answer.  I am happy.  50 rep, well spent.

Answer (score 1):

That's expected, presumably you got a message from latex telling you that the table widths had changed and to re-run latex.

If you re-run latex they should line up.

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|r|r|r|r|}  
Year & To & From &                      Task \\
\endhead
2015    & Jan 8 & Jan 9 &               Bla \\
& Feb 2 & Feb 6 &           Bear \\
& Feb 9 & Mar 6 &               Water \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: alignedtbl]

Comment: Changing the alignment from `l` to `r` does not answer the question, I'm afraid ... unless you can elaborate in your answer and explain why it does answer it.